# How to make thumbnail image 100% width inside a div (on WordPress), and not larger?

Tags: css, image

(First off, let me say I would not ask such a basic-seeming question here if I hadn't tried EVERYTHING I could think of -- manipulating all of the involved variables.

The image loads with this in functions:

```
add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
add_image_size('mobile-thumb', 800, 300);
```

That size (800,300) is a problem. When I display it on mobile, it stubbornly stays 800 wide. I need it 100% width of screen.

I styled it to be

```
div.thumbnail-box {
width:100%;
 height: 100%;
    background-color: #EEE;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-left:0px;
}

.the_post_thumbnail {
 max-width:100%;
}

.desktop-featured-image {
 width:100%;

}
```

I've tried it inside and without that div.

I've adjusted the heights and widths.

My current html is:

```
<div class="thumbnail-box">
                 <img width="800" height="300" src="http://website/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/obama-e1424474715102-800x300.jpg" class="attachment-banner-image wp-post-image" alt="obama-e1424474715102" />           </div>
```

Does anyone know how to simply display a featured image at 100% width of screen?

Thank you

Comment: Neither the .`attachment-banner-image` or the `.wp-post-image` classes are in the CSS you posted.

Comment: You mean you need to reduce the width of the image when using mobile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
img { max-width: 100%; height: auto; }
```

Makes all images scale with the page, if they're larger than their parent div/container/whatever. If you only want to scale the featured images, then this should work:

```
.wp-post-image { max-width: 100%; height: auto; }
```

Comment: Yes, this absolutely worked. Please upvote this answer, people. Just putting that at the bottom of your style.css will show you whether this works for you, and then you can go through your css and find what you need to fix.

Answer (score -1):

Its because your literally telling your image to be 100% of its width.
What is your final goal? to have the width resize to the width of your screen but the height stays the same?

I made some quick examples that i think will point you in the right direction;

```
<h2>flex</h2>
<div style="width: 360px; height: 400px; border: 1px solid blue;">
  <div class="thumbnail-box" style="display: flex;">
    <img class="the_post_thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/800x300" />           
  </div>
</div>

<h2>cover</h2>
<div style="width: 360px; height: 400px; border: 1px solid blue; background-image: url(http://placehold.it/800x300); background-size:cover; background-position: center center;">
</div>

<h2>contain</h2>
<div style="width: 360px; height: 400px; border: 1px solid blue; background-image: url(http://placehold.it/800x300); background-size:contain; background-position: center center;">
</div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/RBVmzVUJFOYl8yXNsy5J?p=preview

I suggest lookup media queries and css flexbox for further explanation.

Comment: The goal, I should have said, is to have the width resize to always be the same width as the screen. The height should maintain proportion.